# Rails w/ Google API Client: header field value cannot include CR/LF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client

```
ArgumentError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#google_oauth2
header field value cannot include CR/LF
```

Really unsure where this error is coming from.

I'm using ruby 2.5, Rails 5, and google-api-client 0.8.2

Any ideas how to fix or what information I can provide to make this question more informative?

**Update:** My logs show this when I am trying to authorize with Google's API

```
Google::APIClient::Request Sending API request get https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest {"User-Agent"=>"hello U/1.0.0 google-api-ruby-client/0.8.2 Mac OS X/10.13.4\n (gzip)", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip", "Content-Type"=>""}
```

And from my research, CRLF is "\r\n" characters, right?

So `"User-Agent"=>"hello U/1.0.0 google-api-ruby-client/0.8.2 Mac OS X/10.13.4\n`
is probably the issue.

So my question would be- how do I access User Agent in my request to fix this issue with Rails 5?

Answer (score 2):

When using the `Google::APIClient`, the generated User-Agent may contains a CRLF. It can can be overridden in constructor. Example :

```
Google::APIClient.new(application_name: 'Foo', application_version: '1.0', user_agent: 'Foo/1.0 google-api-ruby-client/0.8.6 Linux/4.15.0-65-generic (gzip)')
```

Comment: It worked for me. Much simpler than upgrading from 0.7 to 0.20 and to change the code. Thanks!

Comment: Updating did absolutely nothing for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the user_agent string to remove the CR/LF.  I am using Rails 4.1.8 and `google-api-client` version `

```rb
  @api_client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name=>"Chronos", :application_version=>0)
  # work around a bug that puts a CR/LF in the user agent string
  @api_client.user_agent = @api_client.user_agent.gsub("\n", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Update gem `google-api-client` to version `0.20.0`. It solves the problem but requires other changes to the application

Answer (score 0):

Updating the version of the google-api-client gem did the trick for me.